# The return type of <xsl:variable name="pubDate" select="publicationDate" />, a node-set or a string?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xsl and using version 1.0

Here is some xml source

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <publicationDate>03/31/1985</publicationDate>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

From above xml content, I set a varialbe in xsl code by

```
 <xsl:variable name="pubDate" select="//publicationDate" />
```

I thought the variable 'pubDate' should contain a node-set because of '//publicationDate' but then I realized
it is possible to apply String function such as subString($pubDate, 1, 4) which hints that 'pubDate' is also a String.

Is that some automatic type cast or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 `$pubDate` is a node-set. If you were to reference that in a function that expects a string value as a parameter, it will use the string value of the first node in the node set. That is to say, it will get the text value of the node and all descendant nodes. So if your first node actually looked like this:

```
<publicationDate><mm>03</mm><dd>31</dd><yy>1985</yy></publicationDate>
```

Then `substring($pubDate, 1, 4)` will still output `0331`.

Things would be different in XSLT 2.0 though. It would contain a sequence, if you tried the same substring expression you would get the error "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring()"

EDIT: Now, if you had done this...

```
   <xsl:variable name="pubDate">
       <xsl:copy-of select="//publicationDate" />
   </xsl:variable>
```

Then `$pubDate` contains a "Result Tree Fragment". You can still use this in a string function, but it would actually use the string value of the entire result tree fragment in this case.

Comment: Thanks. So the actual value/type of a variable depends on the context of the function, right? Besides, the 'result tree fragment' is a 2.0 stuff or applies to both 1.0 and 2.0?

Comment: The type of the variable remains the same, no matter how it is used. It is still a node-set in this instance. Its just that functions can extract a string value from it, but the variable is still a node-set! Result Tree Fragments only applies to XSLT 1.0 (See http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/951)